# Правописание: (не)пристегнутый

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Как пишется "не" - отдельно или слитно - в таких словосочетаниях: "штраф за езду непристегнутым" и "штраф за непристегнутого пассажира" и почему?

Answer (score 4):

**Штраф за езду непристегнутым.**

**Штраф за непристегнутого пассажира.**

Пристегнутый — причастие; *не* с причастем пишется слитно, если при этом причастии нет зависимых слов.